# How to reset a Pokemon GO account?

Tags: pokemon-go

I accidentally have choosen Bulbasaur for my starter where I wanted Squirtle. Is there anyway to reset it? I have looked in the options menu and there does not appear to be a way to reset it. I guess that I could make a new Google Play account for it, but that seems like a mess.

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe it is possible to reset your account. However, it seems that the starter Pokemon are not extremely rare; I got Bulbasaur as my starter last night and found a Squirtle this morning. Starter Pokemon are not as important as in main-series Pokemon games, anyways.

Comment: @NoahEvans I chose a Charmander last night for my starter. Which was about 7PM when I did that, before I went to bed around 11PM I had already seen approximately 5 Bulbasaur in the area. I just never went to capture them :(

Comment: @C-dizzle welp. I chose bulbasaur on accident. I hope i can find charmander and squirtle as easily.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple - use a laptop/desktop (not mobile device) to log into your Google account. Click the icon on the top right with your photo and click "My Account." On the left hand side, under "Sign-in & Security" click "Connected apps & sites." Under "Apps connected to your account" click "[Manage Apps](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1)." Click Pokemon Go & hit remove.

Comment: It looked like a good idea, but I can't see the "Pokemo Go" in the apps list. :/ Any idea ?

Comment: This doesn't actually remove your data from the Pokémon Go servers—it only revokes their access to your credentials. If you sign back up with the same credentials after doing this, as I just did, you'll be back in the same spot as before.

Comment: No, it doesn't. They store your game data on their own servers. It just happens to use the email address from your Google account. It won't even show up in your connected apps list because they don't require any permissions from your Google account. Why does this have 6 up votes? Do people even try things or just up-vote whatever sounds like a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

When you login to Pokemon Go on android, you have the choice between using your Google account or your Pokemon Club credentials. These two are not linked together, so if you started playing with the Google login, you can start from scratch by making an account on Pokemon Club and playing with it.