# Can't restart pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

I just chose a Pokemon at the start  of the game, but then I realised I could walk away 4 times and get Pikachu.

Is there a way to restart the game?

Comment: Just so you know, the choise of starter is rather irrelevant in Pokemon Go. The game is based heavily on catching the same type/evolution-chain pokemons multiple times. This makes your starter just one pokemon among hundreds of others you catch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot restart a game in Pokemon Go. Fortunately, however, none of the starters, including Pikachu, Squirtle, Bulbasaur, or Charmander, are particularly hard to come by, so you'll be able to catch a Pikachu fairly quickly if you keep playing.

If you're still not satisfied, you could create a new account with a different email and start all over. This would require you to abandon your original account altogether.

Also, please refer to [How to reset a Pokemon GO account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272834/how-to-reset-a-pokemon-go-account), as specified by amaranth.